# Using Javascript in Birt Report (using let)

Tags: javascript, birt

After a thorough search I found a Javascript to convert numbers to proper Arabic text.
I tested this screipt in various js compailer and its works fine. But when I use in BIRT it is throwing error

```js
const TableScales =["","ألف","مليون","مليار","ترليون","كوادرليون","كوينتليون","سكستليون"], // Add here only
      TableScalesP=["","آلاف","ملايين","مليارات"], // Do not change this table
      TableMale   =["","واحد","اثنان","ثلاثة","أربعة","خمسة","ستة","سبعة","ثمانية","تسعة","عشرة"],
      TableFemale =["","واحدة","اثنتان","ثلاث","أربع","خمس","ست","سبع","ثمان","تسع","عشر"];

function nArabicWords(NumIn=0,{Feminine,Comma,SplitHund,Miah,Billions,TextToFollow,AG,Subject,Legal}={}) {
if (NumIn == 0) return "صفر";                          // if 0 or "0" then "zero"
let Triplet, Scale, ScalePos, ScalePlural, TableUnits, Table11_19,NumberInWords= "",IsLastEffTriplet= false,Num_99;
const ON= "on",                         // Flag to test if Option is ON
 IsAG   = (AG===ON),                    // Option Accusative or Genitive case Grammar?
 SpWa   = " و",                         // AND word
 TanweenLetter = "ًا",                   // Tanween Fatih for Scale Names above 10
 Ahad  = "أحد", Ehda= "إحدى",           // Masculine/Feminine 11
 // ---- Setup constants for the AG Option (Accusative/Genitive or Nominative case Grammar)
 Taa   = IsAG ?"تي" :"تا",       Taan   = IsAG ? "تين":"تان",        // Hundred 2's مئتا/مائتا مئتان/مائتان
 Aa    = IsAG ?"ي" :"ا",         Aan    = IsAG ? "ين":"ان",          // Scale 2's الفا/مليونا الفان/مليونان
 Ethna = IsAG ?"اثني":"اثنا",    Ethnata = IsAG ? "اثنتي" : "اثنتا", // Masculine/Feminine 12 starting word
 Ethnan= IsAG ?"اثنين" : "اثنان",Ethnatan= IsAG ? "اثنتين" :"اثنتان",// Masculine/Feminine 2
 Woon  = IsAG ?"ين" :"ون",              // Second part of 20's to 90's
 IsSubject = Array.isArray(Subject) && Subject.length===4;        // Check for Subject Array Names

TextToFollow = TextToFollow === ON;     // TextToFollow Option Flag
if(IsSubject) TextToFollow = true;     // Enable TextToFollow Option if Subject Option is ON
NumIn+="";                              // Make numeric string
NumIn =""+NumIn.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, d => "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩".indexOf(d)); // Convert Arabic-Indic Numbers to Arabic if any
Miah= (Miah===ON) ? "مئة" : "مائة";     // Select chosen Miah (Hundred) Option

TableUnits   = [...TableMale]; Table11_19= [...TableMale]; // Create copies of Masculine Table for manipulation
Table11_19[0]= TableFemale[10];         // Borrow word "عشرة" from Feminine's Table for use in 11-19
Table11_19[1]= Ahad;                    // Masculine starting words for 11
Table11_19[2]= Ethna;                   // Masculine starting words for 12
TableUnits[2]= Ethnan;                  // Masculine word for 2

NumIn = "0".repeat(NumIn.length * 2 % 3) + NumIn;        // Convert Number to a Triplets String

let NumLen = NumIn.length;
for (let digits= NumLen; digits>0; digits-=3) {          // Loop and convert each Triplet
  Triplet = +NumIn.substr(NumLen-digits,3);              // Get a Triplet Number
  IsLastEffTriplet= !+NumIn.substr(NumLen-digits+3);     // Determine if Last Effective Triplet
  if (Triplet) {                                         // If not Empty: Convert Triplet Number to Words
    ScalePos    = digits/3-1;                            // Position of Scale Name in Scale Table
    Scale       = TableScales[ScalePos];                 // Get Scale Name
    ScalePlural = (ScalePos<4 ? TableScalesP[ScalePos] : TableScales[ScalePos] + "ات"); // Make Scale Plural
    if (Billions && ScalePos===3) Scale="بليون", ScalePlural="بلايين";    // If Billions Option
    NumberInWords += oneTripletToWords();                                 // Convert 1 Triplet to Words
    if (!IsLastEffTriplet) NumberInWords+= (Comma===ON ? "،" :"") + SpWa; // Add "و " and Option Comma
  }
} // All done with conversion, Process Subject Name if any
let SubjectName="";
if (IsSubject) {                                          // Process Subject Name
  let space   = !IsLastEffTriplet ? "" : " ";             // Position correct spacing
  Triplet     = +(Triplet+"").slice(-2);                  // Get last 2 digits of last Triplet
  SubjectName = space + Subject[0];                       // Default Subject Name is at Pos 0
  if (Triplet>10)      SubjectName = space + Subject[3];  // Subject name with Tanween for 11-99
  else if (Triplet>2)  SubjectName = space + Subject[2];  // Subject name Plural for 3-10
  else if (Triplet>0)  SubjectName = Subject[Triplet-1]+" "+TableUnits[Num_99];  // Reverse names for 1 or 2
}
 return NumberInWords + SubjectName;                      // All done
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//    Core Function Converts 1 Triplet (1 to 999) to Arabic Words
//------------------------------------------------------------------
function oneTripletToWords() {
    Num_99   = Triplet % 100;               // 00 to 99
let Num_100  = ~~(Triplet/100),             // Hundreds (1 digit)
    Num_Unit = Num_99 % 10,                 // 0 to 9 (1 digit)
    Num_Tens = ~~(Num_99/10),               // Tens   (1 digit)
    Word_100 = "", Word_99= "";             // Holds words for Hundreds & 0-99

if (Feminine === ON && !Scale)  {           // If Feminine, use the Feminine table if no scale
  TableUnits   = [...TableFemale]; Table11_19= [...TableFemale];// Create copies of Feminine Table for manipulation
  Table11_19[0]= TableMale[10];             // Borrow word "عشر" from Masculine's Table for use in 11-19
  Table11_19[1]= Ehda;                      // Feminine starting words for 11
  Table11_19[2]= Ethnata;                   // Feminine starting words for 12
  TableUnits[2]= Ethnatan;                  // Feminine word for 2
  if (Num_99 > 19) TableUnits[1] = Ehda;    // Feminine word for 1 used in 20's to 90's
}

if (Num_100) {                              // ---- Do Hundreds (100 to 900)
 if (Num_100 >2) Word_100 = TableFemale[Num_100] + (SplitHund===ON ?" ":"") + Miah;// 300-900
 else if (Num_100 === 1) Word_100 = Miah;                                          // 100
 else Word_100 = Miah.slice(0,-1) +(Scale && !Num_99 || TextToFollow ?Taa:Taan);   // 200 Use either مئتا or مئتان
}

if (Num_99 >19)  Word_99 = TableUnits[Num_Unit] + (Num_Unit ? SpWa : "") +  // 20-99 Units و and
                 (Num_Tens === 2 ? "عشر" : TableFemale[Num_Tens]) + Woon;   // Add Woon for 20's or 30's to 90's
 else if (Num_99 > 10) Word_99 = Table11_19[Num_99-10] + " " + Table11_19[0]; // 11-19
 else if (Num_99>2 || !Num_99 || !IsSubject) Word_99 = TableUnits[Num_99];  // 0 or 3-10 (else keep void for 1 &2)

let Words999 = Word_100 + (Num_100 && Num_99 ? SpWa:"") + Word_99;          // Join Hund, Tens, and Units

if (Scale) {                                                                // Add Scale Name if applicable
  let legalTxt   = (Legal===ON && Num_99< 3)? " " + Scale : "";             // if Legal Option add Extra Word
  let Word_100Wa = (Num_100 ? Word_100 + legalTxt + SpWa :"") + Scale;      // Default Scale Name
  if (Num_99 > 2) {
    Words999 += " " +                                                       // Scale for for 3 to 99
    (Num_99 >10 ? Scale + (IsLastEffTriplet && TextToFollow ? "":TanweenLetter)// Scale for 11 to 99 (Tanween)
    : ScalePlural);                                                         // Scale for 3 to 10 (Plural)
  } else {
    if (!Num_99)           Words999 += " " +Scale;                          // Scale for 0
    else if (Num_99 === 1) Words999  = Word_100Wa;                          // Scale for 1
    else Words999 = Word_100Wa + (IsLastEffTriplet && TextToFollow ? Aa : Aan);// Scale for 2 ألفا or ألفان
    }
}
return Words999; //Return the Triple in Words
}
}

var Test = 6891829.78;
var FX = float2int(Test);
var FRX = Math.round(frac(Test)*100);

function float2int (value) {
    return value | 0;
}
    
function frac(f) {
    return f % 1;
}
    

console.log( nArabicWords(FX) + "ريال و" +nArabicWords(FRX)+ "هللة فقط ");
```

The error I am getting in Birt is

> - missing ) after formal parameters (nArabicwords.js#6)
>
> org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ) after formal
> parameters (nArabicwords.js#6)
>
> at
> org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
>
> at
> org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:64)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:260)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:328)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:322)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Parser.java:493)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Parser.java:483)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parseFunctionParams(Parser.java:853)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.function(Parser.java:915)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:641)
>
> at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:583)

Anybody having any idea on this?

Comment: Does it support ES6 / destructuring?

Comment: I don't see any reference to `let` in the error message. I think it's complaining about the destructuring in the second argument to the function.

Comment: @epascarello Apparently it supports `const`, so at least that part of ES6. But maybe not destructuring. Probably best to run the code through Babel to make it compatible with older parsers.

Comment: @Barmar I said in general, I have seen if I use let it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

BIRT does not support ES6.
For example, it doesn't know `let` or `const`.